# What actually happens when a photon is absorbed by matter?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, photons, photoelectric-effect

In my physics courses so far we've only discussed the before and after of a photon being absorbed by matter. But what actually happens here? How does the light "meld" with the atom that it is incident upon? What exactly is the mechanism of interaction between matter and the incident photon?

Comment: The atomic system supports multiple energy levels; when the photon  is absorbed, the system gains energy.  If the energy is sufficient, ionization occurs.  For the photoelectric effect we have a very large number of atoms, and a "sea" of loosely connected electrons.  In this case the photon exchanges momentum with the electrons, and if it is in the right direction, and imparts sufficient energy, the electron may be able to exit the surface of the metal .

Comment: On a classical level, the light wave makes the electrons wiggle, and that wiggling makes another light wave that cancels the original one; this is how light waves are absorbed. On the quantum level, you need to quantize the electromagnetic field to see photon absorption. The simplest way is the [Jaynes-Cummings model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaynes%E2%80%93Cummings_model#Formulation) which you should be able to understand after an undergrad QM course.

Comment: A photon is a unit of energy that is being exchanged between a vacuum field and a piece of matter, which, by the way, is also made up from the same fields. Try not to interpret too much into that, more specifically, don't think about it in terms of exchanges of solid bits aka "particles". The entire scientific explanation of these processes happens trough the changes of energy level, angular momentum and spin and, in case of higher energy processes, other quantum numbers.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear (I also shouldn't have mixed absorption with the p.e. effect). What I mean to ask is what exactly is the mechanism of interaction between matter and the incident photon?

Comment: This is an electromagnetic interaction.

Comment: @CuriousOne What you say not to read into is exactly what I want to know about. What is the explanation in terms of fields and other advanced processes? (I should say that I'm a senior in physics)

Comment: If you want to model this "exactly", then you would need quantum electro dynamics, i.e. you would write this (probably with a Feynman diagram) as a scattering event between the a photon, an electron and a phonon, where the photon gets absorbed, the electron changes its momentum and a phonon is excited.

Comment: @CuriousOne The model would tell me the outcome of the interaction but not describe the interaction itself (if that makes sense).

Comment: Go back to my first comment where I warned you not to interpret too much into these things. Physics describes things, it doesn't explain them on some "higher" level. When the description is numerically correct and matches experiments, the physics department's work is done.

Comment: @CuriousOne True. I understand this. I was merely inquiring into whether there is a more detailed description of this process.

Comment: I think you're going a level too deep here. It's correct to ask "what is the mechanism by which _electrons_ interact", and that mechanism is exchange of photons. We have no answer for your question, i.e. "what is the mechanism by which electrons and photons interact". We literally just write down an interaction term. It's our starting point. There is no 'preon' flying between the electron and photon.

Comment: Hmm. You both may be right in suggesting there is currently no such description and I am no field theorist, but I still think a description may exist (perhaps in terms of field amplitudes?). I'm going to do some research and consult some faculty. I'll be back to update.

Comment: Well, for one thing, photons and electrons in Feynman diagrams are perturbation theory, so you are correct, we aren't really describing the entire process, merely a simplified version of it. The entire problem is completely intractable, as it's the equivalent of an infinite many-body problem. The good news is that if you throw an electron with an effective mass and a lattice phonon in there, you can probably reproduce the effect very nicely.

Comment: @CuriousOne Why is it intractable?

Comment: LBM As you could see the question seems to be of minor interest. But it isn't. See my paper about "Are photons composed particles" https://independent.academia.edu/HolgerFiedler

Answer (score 1):

Particles are represented by fluctuations in fields in quantum field theory. So if you have a photon and an electron you will have a corresponding fluctuation in each field. The two fields interact with each other and so the fluctuation in the photon field can influence the fluctuation in the electron field and disappear.

If you want an analogy think of two pieces of string tied together at one end. There is initially a fluctuation in both strings which collide at the string interface. After the collision there is just one larger fluctuation in the string representing the electron field.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the thing within second quantization form: the Hamiltonian contains term like $b^\dagger a_e+\text{h.c}$, which describes the annihilation of a excitation would produce an photon, and its conjugate procedure (which you cares more): absorbing a photon and becoming excited.

This kind of Hamiltonian is derived, in principally, from QuantumElectroDynamics (QED). The Lagrangian contains such a vertex term: matter field (spin-$\frac{1}{2}$ field) couples to light field (spin-$1$ field). Wikipedia gives a clear enough explanation for this.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways a photon can interact with matter, but since the photon is a quantum mechanical entity, one has to define matter in the quantum regime.

In dimensions commensurate to h_bar  matter is composed of atoms in various combinations.

One way of interacting with matter can be seen here: Atoms are modeled by electrons in [orbitals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital) around a positive nucleus of equal and opposite charges. The orbitals are solutions of the quantum mechanical equation and are energy levels. So a photon can be absorbed by an atom by "kicking" an electron to a higher energy level , *if the photon has that energy +/- a quantum mechanical width in the energy.* ( the photon's energy is h*nu, where nu is the frequency of the classical light beam it is a part of). This gives [absorption spectra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorption_spectroscopy), and then when the electron falls back to the lower energy state emission spectra. Momentum is conserved by an excess in motion of the atom that absorbed the photon.

The atoms in matter have also a spill over electric field with which a photon can interact with the [Compton effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compton_scattering), either with single atoms or with a mass of atoms as in a gas, a liquid or a solid. The photon loses part of  its energy and momentum and transfers it to the atoms or molecules , depending on the scatter the energy can be [vibrational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom_(physics_and_chemistry)) energy in a solid or liquid, thus in the end the energy heats matter up, because temperature is connected with the [average kinetic energy of atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temperature#Definition_from_statistical_mechanics)s and molecules.

There are other [more complicated ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B8ller_scattering) of the [photon scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon#Photons_in_matter)  and giving up part of its energy and sequentially be completely absorbed.

Answer (score 0):

The mechanism of interaction is very much the same as a radio wave interacting with an antenna. The "photon" is manifested as oscillations of the electric field, which drive the electron like a mass on a spring. The oscillation frequency is given by the difference between the initial state and the excited state, and you can track the oscillating charge motion calculating the superposition of the two states.

The oscillating electron radiates electromagnetic energy just like any other antenna. Initially, because of the interaction of the radiated field with the incident field, there is actually a net absorption of energy; but eventually the incident field goes away and the atomic system then simply continues to oscillate, re-radiating any residual energy until it returns to the ground state.

You can also analyze this system in terms of "photons" using something called "Fermi's Golden Rule", but it all comes to exactly the same result in terms of what you can actually measure...amount of scattered radiation as a function of the incident field.

DISCLAIMER: I am a recognized crackpot whose opinions are routinely and massively downvoted by the experts in this forum who know much more than me.

Answer (score -3):

I will try in a very general sense, and then you can use your imagination, because books may not answer this for you.

Every interaction takes place via some kind of force. When we push a car, we transfer our energy into the car, but the energy first coverts to force, and then goes into the car. Same way, the photon must transform into a tiny force which would push the electron. That force more than likely has to be electromagnetic repulsion. You can think that the photon field/wave of certain frequency, and field/wave of impacted electron, can not co-exist in space. One transfers its energy to the other, and disappears. This non-ability to co-exist gives rise to repulsion, repulsion gives rise to movement. Paradoxically, they still co-exist post interaction, but as one, not as two.